# makefile ignores $(inputs)

Tags: c++, makefile

Here is makefile:

```
CC=g++
CC_FLAGS=-Wall -march=native -ffast-math -O3
CC_SOURCES=AbsNode.cpp rle16.cpp
CC_OBJECTS=AbsNode.o rle16.o

# Link command:
test : $(CC_OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(CC_OBJECTS) -o test

# Compilation commands: 
%.o:%.cpp
    $(CC) -c $(CC_FLAGS) $(input) -o $(output)
```

when applying make to this makefile, I get the following output:

```
g++ -c -Wall -march=native -ffast-math -O3  -o
g++: arguemnt to '-o' missing
```

Why are inputs and outputs ignored???

Comment: You should copy and paste outputs — or report a misspelling bug to the GCC maintainers for `arguemnt`.

Comment: Traditionally, the name is `CXXFLAGS`.  If you call it `CXXFLAGS`, you can completely remove your rule and let the implicit rules build the object files for you.  Also, `CC` is traditionally the name for the C compiler, and `CXX` is the name for the C++ compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your .cpp -> .o implicit rule is incorrect:

```
%.o: %.cpp
        $(CC) -c $(CC_FLAGS) $< -o $@
```

- `$<` is set by `make` to be the source file
- `$@` will be the output file name

Answer (score 4):

You haven't defined the variables `input` and `output` anywhere. The computer is not a magic box that can guess your intentions.